# Where to declare const struct array

Tags: c++

For an application of my I need multi constant variabels and I have a solution for this, but in my mind I think this is not the correct way.

I will show how i declared this and would like some comment or feedback of this.

file: menu.h

```
#include <QDialog>
...
struct s_button {
   int buttonNum;
   QRect geometry;
   QString iconFileName;
}

namespace Ui {
class Menu;
}
class Menu : public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
...
}
```

file: menu.cpp

```
#include "menu.h"
#include "ui_menu.h"
...
const s_button menuButtons[] =
{
   { 0, QRect(104,120,160,160), "VolumeUp.png"   },
   { 1, QRect(104,300,160,160), "VolumeDown.png" },
   { 2, QRect(104,480,160,160), "Mute.png"       }
};
... 
//Constructor
Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MenuDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ....
}

void Menu::drawMenuButton()
{
     uint s = sizeof(menuButtons) / sizeof(menuButtons[0]);

     for(uint i=0; i<s; i++) {
      drawImage(menuButtons[i].iconFileName, menuButtons[i].geometry);
     }
     ....
}
```

Is this correct way or is there another way to handle this?

Thanks in adavanced

Comment: "in my mind I think this is not the correct way" - we don't read minds. *Why* do you think that?

Comment: For my feeling I thought that this is not the correct way of doing this kind of declaration

Comment: That's just repeated what you said earlier. We get that, but **why** do you think that? There must be *some reason*, otherwise you wouldn't have posted here, right ? Why do you think declaring like that is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const s_button menuButtons[] = {
    { 0, QRect(104,120,160,160), "VolumeUp.png"   },
    { 1, QRect(104,300,160,160), "VolumeDown.png" },
    { 2, QRect(104,480,160,160), "Mute.png"       }
};
```

You CAN DO it like this, it's called **aggregate member initialization**. `{ 0, QRect(104,120,160,160), "VolumeUp.png"   }` will initialize `s_button`'s data members in member order.

Comment: I have a lot of those const s_button in my file, that would not give any problems